# JavaFX: Keypress-Event works for Backspace/Tab/Arrows... but not for character key-codes

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-events, keycode

I'm implementing a custom virtual keyboard (my customer had specific requirements for that). Basically its made of a lot of buttons simulating keyboard events to input characters into text fields.

#### The problem

I found that simulating keypress/keyrelease events for characters have absolutely no effect - even though I could prove that the text field receives those events (through logs). It just doesn't result in a character appearing in the text field.

BUT: Simulating a Backspace/Tab/Arrows with the exact same mechanism works fine. Simulating a character event with a keytype event also works.

#### Background

So why not use keytype events instead? Because of dead characters! I need to support letters with accent like ê (e with ^ on top). Real keyboards make you type those letters by first pressing ^ which is a dead key (no result at first) and then pressing the target letter.

If I send a keytype event for "^" and then another keytype for "e" I get "^e".

#### Code Sample

Here is a minimal code sample with 5 buttons:

- Keypress e: Text field receives event (I see console output) but no effect
- Keypress ^: Text field receives event (I see console output) but no effect
- Keypress Backspace: Works, last character is deleted
- Keytype e: works, letter "e" appears
- Keytype ^: works, a single "^" appears but not on top of the "e"

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            log.info("Keypress Event: " + e.getCode());
        });
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
            log.info("KeyRelease Event: " + e.getCode());
        });
        textField.setOnKeyTyped(e -> {
            log.info("KeyType Event: " + e.getCharacter());
        });

        // Doesn't work
        Button keypressLetterButton = new Button();
        keypressLetterButton.setText("e (keypress)");
        keypressLetterButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            pressKeyCode(KeyCode.E, textField);
        });

        Button keypressCircumflexButton = new Button();
        keypressCircumflexButton.setText("^ (keypress)");
        keypressCircumflexButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            pressKeyCode(KeyCode.DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX, textField);
        });

        // Works
        Button keypressBackspaceButton = new Button();
        keypressBackspaceButton.setText("Backspace");
        keypressBackspaceButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            pressKeyCode(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE, textField);
        });

        Button keytypeLetterButton = new Button();
        keytypeLetterButton.setText("e (keytype)");
        keytypeLetterButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            typeKey("e", textField);
        });

        // Works, but not as intended
        Button keytypeCircumflexButton = new Button();
        keytypeCircumflexButton.setText("^ (keytype)");
        keytypeCircumflexButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            typeKey("^", textField);
        });

        // Just to prevent stealing focus
        keypressLetterButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
        keypressCircumflexButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
        keypressBackspaceButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
        keytypeLetterButton.setFocusTraversable(false);
        keytypeCircumflexButton.setFocusTraversable(false);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(keypressLetterButton, keypressCircumflexButton, keypressBackspaceButton,
                keytypeLetterButton, keytypeCircumflexButton, textField);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void pressKeyCode(KeyCode keyCode, Node target) {
        KeyEvent pressEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, null, keyCode.getName(), keyCode, false, false, false,
                false);
        KeyEvent releaseEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, null, keyCode.getName(), keyCode, false, false,
                false, false);
        target.fireEvent(pressEvent);
        target.fireEvent(releaseEvent);
    }

    public void typeKey(String key, Node target) {
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, key, null, null, false, false, false, false);
        target.fireEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: I think most of this is expected behavior. You should send `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` events when the button is pressed, followed by a `KEY_TYPED` event if the press-release represents typing a character (and typically you'd check, e.g. if shift is held down to determine the character). I am not sure about the "dead key"; I've not used a keyboard that works like that. (On my Mac, you hold down the 'e' key, and most software will give you options for e with various accents. You could mimic that with a split menu button, which might be a better UX anyway.)

Comment: If you do need the "dead key" approach, then you just need to hold some state about which dead key(s) are pressed, update that state when those buttons are pressed, and modify the string that is passed to the `KEY_TYPED` event according to that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to simulate the KEY_TYPED event as well, for keys that type a character.  That's just how the framework works.  It is possible to press and release keys without typing a character (for example if CTRL was already down), so they are separate events.
You can also get multiple KEY_TYPED events if a key is held down.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of swpalmer I want to share a workaround that on the one hand does what I was looking for, but on the other hand (mis-)uses an old Java AWT class. The main point is that it proves that a KEY_TYPED event is necessary.

```
    private java.awt.Robot robot;

    public TestApplication() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void pressKeyCode(KeyCode keyCode, Node target) {
        robot.keyPress(keyCode.impl_getCode()); // Deprecated
        robot.keyRelease(keyCode.impl_getCode()); // Deprecated
    }
```

Pressing Dead Circumflex followed by e produces this log:

```
10:15:26.725 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO test.TestApplication - Keypress Event: DEAD_CIRCUMFLEX
10:15:31.091 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO test.TestApplication - Keypress Event: E
10:15:31.091 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO test.TestApplication - KeyType Event: ê
10:15:31.092 [JavaFX Application Thread] INFO test.TestApplication - KeyRelease Event: E
```

So the Robot class internally fires a KEY_TYPED event for ê.

However:

- Robot class is old and was mostly intended to test automatisation.
- It uses integers instead of KeyCode
- and the method `keyCode.impl_getCode()` is deprecated in Java 8 and propably doesn't exist any more. So in the future I'd have to manually convert KeyCode to integer.

So my finaly solution will be that I manage the letters including accents within the KEY_TYPED events myself.